# UITextField: Add margin between cursor and placeholder text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Is it possible to customize the margin between the the cursor and the placeholder text?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass UITextField and override `placeholderRect(forBounds:)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619615-placeholderrect